# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function <function_name>(integer, unknown, unknown) does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, backend

I'm in the process of setting up the backend environment for a mobile app on my local machine and a Postgres function call within a Ruby model errors out the request. Here's the log:

```
D, [2015-08-05T23:10:06.029187 #1732] DEBUG -- :   Game Load (2.0ms)   SELECT field1, field2, field3
 FROM valuestable 
 WHERE ARRAY[field1] && (
 SELECT custom_function(3, '{}', 'ipad')
 );

E, [2015-08-05T23:10:06.029262 #1732] ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function custom_function(integer, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 4:           SELECT custom_function(3, '{}', 'ipad')
                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
          SELECT field1, field2, field3
          FROM gamestable 
          WHERE ARRAY[field1] && (
          SELECT custom_function(3, '{}', 'ipad')
        );
```

We use Postgres 9.4.1/Redis/Rails/AWS.

The `custom_function` in the above sql query is defined in a class that got auto created during a migration. I see it in one of the time-stamped `.rb` files in the `db/migrate` folder of the said ruby app. However, I do not know how to "include/import" that into my model so this error can be prevented. I have an sql file called `user_functions.sql` authored by one of my ex-colleagues in which the `custom_function` (from the above error) is referenced.

Also, another interesting point is this application runs perfectly on both Staging and Production. It's only on the local machine that it doesn't work. I have no idea if this is some kind of a one-time setup on the backend run directly on AWS or if it's simply a step I'm missing while setting up my local backend.

Meta Information: I'm originally an iOS dev, trying to figure out some backend logic in the absence of a real backend person.

What I tried so far:

- Making sure the version number of Postgres matches on server and local backend
- Trying to use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("/path/to/user_functions.sql")) just before `custom_function` is first called.

Answer (score 0):

Look what arguments custom function is expecting and cast them.
like this: instead of `SELECT custom_function(3, '{}', 'ipad')` use `SELECT custom_function(3, '{}'::json, 'ipad'::text)` or `SELECT custom_function(3, '{}'::text, 'ipad'::text)` cos many types can go inside the quotes